# Check list lst if it's a geometric sequence in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, sequence

I have,

```
def geometric(lst):
'checks whether the integers in list lst form a geometric sequence'
    for i in range(1, len(lst) - 1):
        if lst[i] * 2  == "don't know what to check here":
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I'm not sure how to apply that to check if all the indices. Would prefer this done within a for-loop. any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should understand the math when you want to write an algorithm http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sequences-sums-geometric.html

Answer (score 4):

I think this works:

```
def geometric(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst) - 2):
        if lst[i] * lst[i + 2] != lst[i + 1] ** 2:
            return False
    return True
```

This is based on the idea that for any three consecutive terms `a, b, c`, the ratio between the first two must equal the ratio between the last two, i.e. `b/a = c/b`. Rearranging this gives `a * c == b ** 2`. It's much better to use the form without division, because division introduces rounding errors. This function even works if the common ratio is not an integer (e.g. `[4, 6, 9]`).

**Edit**

The above answer does not handle lists containing `0` correctly.

A correct version is:

```
def geometric(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst) - 2):
        if lst[i] * lst[i + 2] != lst[i + 1] ** 2:
            return False
    for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
        if lst[i] == 0 and lst[i + 1] != 0:
            return False
    return True
```

This returns `True` for `[1, 0, 0]` (common ratio `0`) but `False` for `[0, 0, 1]`. The original version returned `True` for both.

It may be better to disallow common ration `0`. This would mean changing the second loop to return `False` for any list of length `2` or more containing `0`.

Comment: probably the lack of any explanation

Answer (score 1):

As sam2090 has pointed out, the right side of the condition in line 4 has been left empty. If the common ratio of the geometric sequence is 2 (maybe it's something that you would actually want to pass as a parameter of the function), then the expression should be:

```
if lst[i] == lst[i-1] * 2
```

The left-hand side of the statement refers to the current number in the itertion (i), while the right-hand side of the statement refers to the previous number (i-1) and multiplies its value by 2.

Also, in the `foor` loop, be sure you iterate until the last element in the list, so you should write:

```
for i in range(1, len(lst)):
```

and not

```
for i in range(1, len(lst) - 1):
```